How to Change dist Directory Structure After NX Build for Angular Publishable Libraries
I'm working on an NX Angular application with multiple publishable libraries. Currently, after running nx build, the dist directory has the following structure:
current:
dist
└── libs
    └── ui-kit
        └── components
            └── button

desired:
dist
└── ui-kit
    └── button

*project.json:
...
  "projectType": "library",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:package",
      "outputs": [
        "{workspaceRoot}/dist/{projectRoot}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "project": "libs/ui-kit/ng-package.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/ui-kit/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
        },
        "development": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/ui-kit/tsconfig.lib.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
...

image:

Is there a way to change the default output directory structure after building the libraries? Specifically, I want to avoid the additional libs and components layers in the dist folder.
I've checked the nx.json and project.json files but haven't found a clear way to adjust the path in the build process.
Any advice or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Why do you want to mix libs and apps? They need to be handled very differently. One needs to be published via npm so it can be installed in other apps, the other one needs to be put to a web server. To me it makes perfect sense to have separate folders.

I'm not changing the app's path; I just want to change the output for the library. I want the import module to be @org/ui-kit/button instead of @org/ui-kit/components/button. I can achieve this by simply removing the components folder in the libs, but I need to keep it for better code organization.

If you only need to move a folder and doing so doesn't break any internal references in your code, you can use the nx:run-commands executor to run the build and commands to move the files as required after.
The nx:run-commands allows you to run any commands you want as a NX target.
If you rename your current build task to something else, such as build-angular, you can create a new task called build. The new task simply needs to set the executor and commands to run:
"targets": {
  "build-angular": {
    // Existing Angular build config...
  },
  "build": {
    "executor": "nx:run-commands",
    "options": {
      "commands": [
        "npx nx run ui-kit:build-angular",
        "mkdir dist/ui-kit",
        "mv dist/libs/ui-kit/components/button dist/ui-kit/button",
        "rm -r dist/libs"
      ]
    }
  }
},

Alternatively, you can keep the build name for the Angular task and give the new target a different name, like build-move.
You may need to adapt the commands above depending on your operating system. If you want to make them cross-platform, you could use inline evaluated JavaScript with Node.js to make the required changes, using something like this:
"commands": [
  "npx nx run ui-kit:build-angular",
  "node -e \"fs.mkdirSync('dist/ui-kit');\"",
  "node -e \"fs.renameSync('dist/libs/ui-kit/components/button', 'dist/ui-kit/button');\"",
  "node -e \"fs.rmSync('dist/libs', { recursive: true });\""
];

You could also create a script to make the changes and call that from the task:
"commands": [
  "npx nx run ui-kit:build-angular",
  "node post-build-move.js"
];

